# Qual é a melhor forma de usar FirstChanceException em aplicação multithreading?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, multithreading

Tenho uma aplicação (que é um serviço do Windows) que atualmente executa N Threads. O que eu quero fazer é capturar **qualquer** erro que ocorra na aplicação para gravar em um arquivo de log '.txt'. Só que quero fazer isso de forma **global**.

Estou usando o evento `FirstChanceException`, só que este evento executa apenas por [AppDomain](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.8) e se fosse para registrar o evento apenas na thread principal da aplicação, todos os erros seriam gravados em um único arquivo '.txt', causando bastante concorrência e etc.

Então pensei em criar vários [AppDomains](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains?view=netframework-4.8) (cada `AppDomain` com uma dessas Threads que tenho na aplicação) para capturar as `exceptions` de cada Thread. Fiz uma aplicação de teste e isso funciona: no final tenho um arquivo de log para cada Thread.

Só que minhas dúvidas são:

1. Esta é a melhor forma de capturar globalmente exceções em aplicações com N Threads? Teria outra forma de fazer isso?
2. Criar um AppDomain para cada Thread não vai gerar alguma sobrecarga de processos no S.O.?
3. Se estourar erro no FirstChanceException, vai ter um loop infinto de erros. Ainda mais no caso de escrever em arquivo texto. Teria alguma alternativa do FirstChanceExpception?

Pesquisas que já fiz:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains?view=netframework-4.8

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.8

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=netcore-2.2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569580/exceptions-in-multithreaded-application/43934857

**Abaixo segue o que fiz para teste:**

```
public class Program
{

    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim lock_ = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
            {
                GravarLog(e.Exception);
            };

            AppDomain domain1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Consumidor-1");
            domain1.FirstChanceException += (object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
                        {
                            GravarLog(e.Exception);
                        };

            Consumer consumer1 = (Consumer)domain1.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                                          typeof(Consumer).Assembly.FullName,
                                          typeof(Consumer).FullName);

            consumer1.Iniciar();


            AppDomain domain2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Consumidor-2");
            domain2.FirstChanceException += (object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
            {
                GravarLog(e.Exception);
            };

            Consumer consumer2 = (Consumer)domain2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                                          typeof(Consumer).Assembly.FullName,
                                          typeof(Consumer).FullName);

            consumer2.Iniciar();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void GravarLog(Exception exception)
    {

        lock_.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            File.AppendAllText($"D:\\Temp\\Log\\Thread-{Thread.GetDomainID()}-error.txt",
                         DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ff") + " - " +
                         $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName} -> FirstChanceException: {exception.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            lock_.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

}

    public class Consumer : MarshalByRefObject
{        
    public void Iniciar()
    {

        var tarefa = new Thread(() =>
        {

            int contador = 1;

            while (true)
            {
                contador++;

                var resultado = VerificarRegras();

                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }

        });

        tarefa.Start();

    }

    public string VerificarRegras()
    {

        string regraNegocio = "Tudo OK!";

        try
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Thrown Exception" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch
        {
            regraNegocio = "A validação da regra retornou...";
        }

        return regraNegocio;
    }

}
```

Comment: Porque o seu trabalho de `Threads` não é gerenciado por uma classe comum, onde nesta classe há o gerenciamento de exceções? Imagine uma classe `ThreadManager` que possui um objeto `Thread`. Você podera fazer esta classe receber um `Action`, onde o `constructor` da classe receberia esta action. Uma função private com o nome, por exemplo, `DoWork()` (exemplo) invocaria esta `Action` com um try-catch global. O log é gerado gerado baseado no `ThreadId`. E ao invés de você spawnar N `threads`, você spawna N gerenciadores de `thread`.

Comment: Talvez até tenha outras coisas para fazer que poderiam deixar sua solução melhor, mas somente poderia dizer conhecendo o caso. Porque fico na dúvidas porque N threads, por exemplo

Comment: @KevinKouketsu na verdade hoje tem 42 Threads na aplicação, mas este número pode subir. O que acontece: a aplicação processa mensagens que foram enviadas pelo middleware RabbitMQ. Cada Thread é um `Consumidor` / `Assinante` de uma fila de mensagens no RabbitMQ, e tem a tarefa de receber e processar cada mensagens. Na verdade cada Thread representa uma "tarefa/processo" para processar mensagem. Se ao invés de cada thread fosse criado um processo, teria todo o escalonamento do sistema operacional e no gerenciador de tarefas do Windows iriam aparecer 42 ".exe". Por isso optei pelas Threads.